# Project management

Tags: soft-question

What book or MOOC would you recommend on work organisation / management of academic research projects? (Does not have to be academic project management specifically, but as close as possible)

Comment: Are you looking for content specifically about managing CS theory projects? With what level of student? (Secondary school, undergrad, masters, phd, postdoc, etc) You might get a broader pool of responses on academia.stackexchange, but they might also be less specific to CS Theory, so it might depend on what you're looking for.

Comment: CS theory projects (but I don't really need advice on how to work on a project), phd students and postdocs mainly. I am not new neither to the field not to project management, but I'm always looking for possible growth points.